# Check value of text field and alert if different set in js

Tags: javascript

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="promoCode">
</form>
```

I have a text input field in a form and trying to have a js function that has a promo code in the js and if someone puts anything different to whats in the js then triggers an alert saying 'Promo Code Incorrect'

I'm really bad a js but here is a very bad example of what I'm trying to do.

```
<script>

    (#promoCode)='promo123sep'

   else
     alert('Promo Code Invalid')

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If u use jQuery, code should look like this.

    <script>
// set var
        var promoCode = 'promo123sep';
// if var is not equal to input
        if($('#promoCode').val() !== promoCode){
// alert        
        alert('Promo Code Invalid');

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
if($('#promocode').val()=='promo123sep'){
  // some code
}
else{
 alert('Promo Code Invalid')
}
```

or using simple js

```
if(document.getElementById('promocode').value != 'promo123sep')
   alert("promo code invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be like so:

```
// Get the element using it's id, and then get the value
var inputPromoCode = document.getElementById('promoCode').value

// Check the value against the stored value
if(inputPromoCode === 'promo123sep'){
  alert('good');
} else {
  alert('Promo Code Invalid');
}
```

But I highly not agree. I suggest you do this on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of an html element in JS, you first need to get the reference of that object through most likely it's id, like:

```
document.getElementById("promoCode");
```

Then in order to get it's value:

```
document.getElementById("promoCode").value;
```

Then you can compare it with your designated promo value and do whatever you wish:

```
if(document.getElementById("promoCode").value != "promo123sep")
    alert("Promo Code Invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="promoCode" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('#promoCode').on('blur', function() {

        if($(this).val() === 'promo123sep') {
             alert('The same');
        } else {
             alert('Promo Code Invalid');   
        }

   });
});
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzbo35x5/)

**EDIT:**

If you want to make it simple with JavaScript you can do this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="promoCode" onblur = "validate()" />
</form>

<script>
    function validate() {
        var value = document.getElementById('promoCode').value;
        if(value === 'promo123sep') {
            alert('The same');
        } else {
            alert('Promo Code Invalid');   
        }

    }
</script>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzbo35x5/3/)